# Virtuoso - HTTPS enabled SPARQL endpoint

Tags: database, api, https, sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to access Virtuoso's default SSL-enabled SPARQL endpoint on the instance running on my server. In the conductor interface at

```
http://localhost:8890/conductor/
```

I see in the 'Virtual Directories' tab that the port for the default non-SSL endpoint is shown as 8890, but there is no port assigned to the default SSL endpoint. How can I enable access to this endpoint?

Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: Regarding the HTTPS listener, I suggest you start with [the relevant documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSetupSSL) where we try to provide clear instructions for all such tasks... If that doesn't work, then please describe how your experience departs from the documentation.

Comment: Most questions specifically regarding [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com)  (from my employer) are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).